# Java. Из String в StringBuilder

Tags: java, строки

Изучаю Java. Имеется переменная String, необходимо создать переменную StringBuilder с её значением (для того, чтобы в последствии созданную переменную изменить и сравнить со String). Не могу понять, как это сделать, на оператор "=" ругается. Подскажите, как это сделать и почему не работает в данном случае оператор "=", где можно почитать на этот счёт.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/260767/ вот тут статейка с хабры на великом и могучем))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringBuilder` - это другой класс, не то что `String`, что создать его на основе строки нужно применить конструктор, то есть:

```
String z = "Xxxx";
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(z);
```

А для сравнение нужно использовать метод `compareTo()`, т.к. java для экономии памяти одинаковые строки ссылают на один участок памяти.
Почитать можно "Java: полное руководство"

Answer (score 1):

`String` и `StringBuilder` это два разных типа (класса). Прямого приведения к нужному типу не получится.

Для того, чтобы `String` преобразовать в `StringBuilder` необходимо для начала создать экземпляр класса StringBuilder, а потом передать туда значение String либо через конструктор `StringBuilder(String str)` либо через метод `append(Object obj)`.

С помощью метода `append()` так же можно добавлять текст к уже существующему экземпляру класса `StringBuilder`:

```
String s = “Hello World”;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(s);

System.out.print(sb);
```

Comment: Извините, но никак не пойму, откуда взялась `s` в вашем коде?

Comment: Упс... Исправил